# Why do I receive Name error: function is not defined

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing a kivy application with python.I have defined two functions within the same widget (update and on_touch_down). The second function which is the built in "on_touch_down" function calls the first function. The idea is to call the first function when the user clicks the screen. However once I run the app and click the screen, the receive the error:

```
File : "main.py", line 57, in on_touch_down
   update()
NameError: name 'update' is not defined
```

And here is the code causing the issue :

```
class childWidget(Widget):
    def update():
        for s in range(len(root.markers)):
            root.map.remove_marker(root.marker[s])
        root.markers.clear()
        cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM aircraft;")
        new_table = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in new_table():
            markers.append(MapMarker(lon= row[2], lat=row[1], source='if_plane-b_86362.png'))
            root.map.add_marker(MapMarker(lon= row[2], lat=row[1], source='if_plane-b_86362.png'))

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        update()
```

Comment: Because it's a method on the same object, try `self.update()`.

Comment: A class does not define a new scope. Since `update` isn't defined locally inside `on_touch_down`, the next place to look up the name is the global scope (or more specifically, the scope in which `childWidget` is defined), not in the body of the `class` statement.

Comment: @jonrcharpe When I do that i get the error:  update() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

Comment: @Flower yes...because you're missing `self` in the definition and then you're most likely missing referring to `self` in quite a few of the variables you're trying to access... (`root.markers` would probably become `self.root.markers` for instance)

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the following lines:

Line 2 when you create the update() method:

```
def update(self):
```

and line 14 when you call the method:

```
self.update()
```